# How to use IEnumerable in form razor page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a form for create page in razor pages to fill organization details.
The organization has a field ParentId(it might belong to another organisation).
I want to iterate list of parentIds (and show Title in options) in Select.
I am getting this error: ***The following sample generates CS1579 because the MyCollection class doesn't contain the public GetEnumerator method***:

```
//Model
public class Organisation : EntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Organisation Parent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
}

//Controller
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            IEnumerable<Organisation> objList = _db.Organisations;
            return View(objList);
        }

//View

        @model MindNavigatorDB.Entities.Organisation;
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="Parent" class="control-label"></label>
           <select id="country"
                class="form-select form-control"
                asp-for="Parent"
                aria-label="Select">
                @foreach (Organisation item in Model)
                {
                   <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
                }
                                
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parent" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>                 
        </form>
```

Comment: Posted code does not appear to contain a class called MyCollection

Answer (score 0):

you have to add  ParentId to Orgainzation

```
public class Organisation : EntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Organisation Parent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Create view model

```
public class OrganizationViewModel
{
    public Organization {get; set;}
    public  List<SelectListItem>     ParentSelectList  {get; set;}
}
```

action

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
   var viewModel= new OrganizationViewModel
  {
     Organization=new Organization(),
      ParentSelectList = _db.Organisations.Select( i=> new SelectListItem
       { 
        Value=i.Id.ToString(),
       Text=i.Title
       }).ToList()                                         
   }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

view

```
 @model OrganisationViewModel;

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
<label  class="control-label"> Parent </label>
 <select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Organization.ParentId" asp-items="@Model.ParentSelectList" ></select>
 <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Organization.ParentId" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>                 
 </form>
```